# PHP - Blogger API time format to milliseconds

Tags: php, timestamp, blogger, milliseconds

I am bit confused with the blogger timestamp to milliseconds in blogger API.

```
2018-01-26T07:06:00-08:00
```

I do know how to convert from date to milliseconds

```
$seconds = $milliseconds / 1000;
$date = date("d M Y, D", $seconds);
```

But this is not a normal format of a date, I am not able to crack the blogger timestamp and convert it to milliseconds. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo strtotime("2018-01-26T07:06:00-08:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and format the date as follows

```
$dateStr = "2018-01-26T07:06:00-08:00";
$date = date("d M Y, D", strtotime($dateStr));
```

> Output: 26 Jan 2018, Fri

[Working Link](https://eval.in/942992)